# Why did Harry Potter want Dobby not to save him?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry Potter says to Dobby:

> Harry Potter: **Never try to save my life again**.

Why did Harry Potter want Dobby not to save him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harry was speaking in jest, but making a serious point.

Dobby had tried to save his llfe, but done so in n unacceptable way, ie by keeping him away from Hogwarts and his friends there, and intercepting his mail.

Harry was telling Dobby that such interference with Harry's freedom of choice was wrong, however honourable the motives.

Comment: This answer misses the rather obvious point that one of Dobby's methods of "saving" Harry from Voldemort was to try to seriously injure, if not kill, him with a Bludger during a Quidditch match.

Comment: Yes, I'd forgotten that Dobby did that. Of course it makes Harry's comment all the more pointed.

Answer (score 8):

This is a classic case of "the cure is worse than the disease". In the course of trying to save Harry's life, Dobby did the following:

- He stole all of Harry's mail.
- He got Harry in trouble with the Ministry for using magic at home.
- He caused the Dursleys to lock Harry in a room for the remainder of the summer (until he was rescued).
- He prevented Harry from boarding the train to school, which almost resulted in Harry's expulsion.
- He set a Bludger on a rampage after Harry, which ended up breaking Harry's arm and leading to Harry losing all the bones in his arm, and potentially could have done even more damage.

Harry was quite distressed by these unintended consequences:

> “No,” said Harry angrily. “Give me my friends’ letters!”

> Dobby might have saved Harry from horrible happenings at Hogwarts, but the way things were going, he’d probably starve to death anyway.

> “You nearly got Ron and me expelled,” he said fiercely. “You’d better get lost before my bones come back, Dobby, or I might strangle you.”

> “Your Bludger?” said Harry, anger rising once more. “What d’you mean, your Bludger? You made that Bludger try and kill me?”
>
> “Not kill you, sir, never kill you!” said Dobby, shocked. “Dobby wants to save Harry Potter’s life! Better sent home, grievously injured, than remain here, sir! Dobby only wanted Harry Potter hurt enough to be sent home!”

Thus, Harry is telling Dobby, perhaps slightly in jest, that he is better off without Dobby trying to save him.